# Strong numbers in python

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x

A number is strong number if the sum of the factorials of the individual digits is equal to the number itself.
For example: 145 = 1! + 4! +5!

I wrote the following code in python for this:

```
import math
def strong_num():
    return [x for x in range(1,1000) if x==int(reduce(lambda p,q:math.factorial(int(p))+math.factorial(int(q)),str(x)))]

print strong_num()
```

but the interpreter never returns??
What is wrong with this code?

Comment: I am trying to use the `lambda` here.... i know there are other ways to do it.... check this http://ideone.com/8cERCb

Comment: It's easier to understand what the code does if you do it in steps, instead of in one long near unreadable line.

Comment: just for the curiosity: `print "0, 1, 2, 145, 40585"` would solve the problem, too

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `reduce` input is wrong, the you shouldn't compute the factorial of `p`. In fact, it is easier to just use `sum`:

```
return [x for x in range(1, 1000) 
          if x == sum(math.factorial(int(q)) for q in str(x))]
```

---

The [`functools.reduce`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) function can be  considered as:

```
reduce(f, [a, b, c, d, ...]) == f(f(f(a, b), c), d) ...
```

So, for instance, if x == 145, then your `reduce` part will compute

```
   int(reduce(lambda p, q: factorial(int(p)) + factorial(int(q)), str(x)))
== int(reduce(lambda p, q: factorial(int(p)) + factorial(int(q)), "145"))
== int(factorial(factorial(1) + factorial(4)) + factorial(5))
== int(factorial(1 + 24) + 120)
== int(15511210043330985984000000 + 120)
== 15511210043330985984000120
```

The interpreter doesn't finish likely because of needing to compute the factorial of an extremely large number (consider (2 × 9!)!...)

If you still need to keep the `reduce`, you should change it to:

```
 reduce(lambda p,q: p + math.factorial(int(q)),  str(x),  0)
#                   ^                                     ^
#                   No need to factorial                  Add initializer too
```

Comment: isn't what you said is a different way of doing it??

Comment: is it wrong to use `lambda` in this scenario?? we use it for sum of numbers right? y not here??

Answer (score 0):

**What is Strong number?**

Strong number are those numbers whose sum of factorial of digits is equal to the original number.
**For example:**
 *145 is strong number.* Since, 1! + 4! + 5! = 145

```
num = int(input("Enter any number"))
user_given_no=num
i = 0
fact = 1
fact_list = []
diff_no = []
while num != 0:
    i = num % 10
    num = num//10
    diff_no.append(i)


for y in diff_no:

    x = y
    fact = 1
    while x != 0:
        fact *= x

        x -= 1
    fact_list.append(fact)

sum = 0
for x in fact_list:
    sum += x

if sum == user_given_no:
    print("Strong number")
else:
   print("Not a Strong number")
```

Answer (score 0):

***Strong number are those numbers whose sum of factorial of digits is equal to the original number.***
So, a simple program here to find the strong number in a list of python.

```
def factorial(number):
    if(number == 0 or number == 1):
        fact = 1
    else:
        fact = number * factorial(number - 1)
    return fact

def strong_number(list):
    new_list=[]
    for x in list:
        temp = x
        sum = 0
        while(temp):
            rem = temp % 10
            sum += factorial(rem)
            temp = temp // 10
        if(sum == x):
           new_list.append(x)
        else:
           pass  
    return new_list

# Example 1
val_list = [1,2,5,145,654,34]
strong_num_list = strong_number(val_list)
print(strong_num_list)
# Example 2 and this will return an empty list as there is no strong number found in 
the list that is passed
val_list2 = [5,10,14,34,45]
strong_num_list = strong_number(val_list2)
print(strong_num_list)
```

Now, if you do not not want to pass a list just simply remove the for loop from the function strong_number.
Happy Learning!!!

Answer (score 0):

```py
import math
x=(input("enter the number\n"))

y=[int(i) for i in x]
#print("digits of the entered number:\n",y)

z=list((math.factorial(i) for i in y))
#print("factorial of each digit of given number:\n",z)

z=sum(z)
#print("sum of factorials of each digit of the given number:\n",z)


if z==int(x): print(x,"is a Strong Number")
else: print(x,"is not a Strong Number ")
```

Answer (score -1):

You are not properly decomposing the number into its component digits. You need reduce to operate the lambda over a list of integers, and str(x) does not produce a list of integers.

Comment: Sorry - I got the wrong hang of it. I didn't see your taking the int. I think the other guy got the right answer.